# Simple majority probability

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am having trouble verifying if my calculations are correct, professor hasn't taught us yet assigned us these type of problems.

> Suppose that Michael and Robby are each running for mayor of LA. It is known that
>   55% of Merced voters prefer Robby to Michael. A simple majority is necessary to become the
>   mayor of LA.
>
> 1. If 41 people vote on election day, what are the odds that Robby will become the mayor of
>      LA?

$$55\% \text{ of } 41 = 0.55 \cdot 41 = 22.55 \approx 23$$
So 23 people will vote for Robby and $41 - 23 = 18$ people will vote for Michael.
Then the odds are $23 - 18 = 5$ in favor of Robby.

> 2. If 401 people vote on election day, what are the odds that Robby will become the mayor
>      of LA?

$$55 \% \text{ of } 401 = 220.55 \approx 221$$
Then 221 people will vote for Robby and $401 - 221 = 180$ people will vote for Michael.
Then the odds are $221 - 180 = 41$ odds in favor of Robby.

Comment: I think you are expected to assume the $41$ or $401$ voters are a random sample of the population, so each voter has an independent $55\%$ chance of voting for Robby.  You are then expected to find the chance that Robby wins a majority.  In your answer to a, it is correct that the expected number of votes for Robby is $22.55$, but it is incorrect to interpret $23-18$ as odds of $5$ (whatever that means) in favor of Robby.

Comment: If 23 vote for Robby and 18 vote for Michael then Robby wins with 100% probability. The idea is that you don't _know_ Robby will get 23 votes; all you know is that each of the 41 voters is 55% likely to vote for him. There is even a (very very tiny) chance that he will get no votes at all.

Comment: The *odds* are closer to $3:1$ and $44:1$ though I suspect your are actually being asked for probabilities, possibly using a normal approximation.

Comment: In both problems, you are supposed (not quite reasonably) to assume that each voter who shows up has a probability $0.55$ of voting for Robby. Then you are to determine, in the first problem, the probability Robby gets $22$ or more votes. For this, in principle, you should use the binomial distribution, but you may be expected to use the normal approximation to the binomial. Similar calculation for more voters.